# How can I remove an element whose ID starts with "A" and ends with "Z"?

Tags: jquery

I have the following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if ($("input[id^='ABCD']").$("input[id$='Z']")) {           
            $("input[id^='ABCD']").$("input[id$='Z']").remove();
        }
    })
</script>
```

And I want to remove the elements whose ID starts with "ABCD" and ends with "Z".
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can combine those to match elements that both starts with `ABCD` and ends with `Z`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[id^='ABCD'][id$='Z']").remove();
});
```

this removes something like `<div id="ABCD_something_Z" ...`

To remove elements starting with `ABCD` ***AND*** elements ending with `Z`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[id^='ABCD'], input[id$='Z']").remove();
});
```

this removes `<div id="ABCDEF">` and `<div id="crapZZZ">`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. It might be a little quicker if you're working with a lot of elements.

```
$('input').filter(function(){
  return this.id.slice(0,4) === 'ABCD' && this.id.slice(-1) === 'Z';
}).remove();
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/fahupube/1/edit?html,js,output